# Javascript link when clicked loads jQuery menu. Everything loads but doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, bookmarklet, jquery-load

I am trying to create a bookmarklet Javascript link that when clicked it will load up a menu over the current page. So far when I click the link, all the markup html, CSS, and jQuery code loads up, however, it does not execute. In other words, the menu open button does not open the menu...

I noticed that when the code is loaded normally on a page not using the link bookmarklet, classes are dynamically added to the nav and ul li tags. This doesn't happen when the scripts and markup are loaded through the bookmarklet. Below is my code.

Bookmarklet Javascript link:

```
<a href="javascript:(function () { var jsCode = document.createElement('script'); jsCode.setAttribute('src', 'file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/public/bookmarklet/poolapp.js'); document.body.appendChild(jsCode); }());">Run Bookmarklet</a>
```

Script that creates the markup and adds the necessary jQuery for the menu:

```
(function(){    
    // the minimum version of jQuery we want
    var v = "1.7.2";

    // check prior inclusion and version
    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery < v) {
        var done = false;
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + v + "/jquery.min.js";
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
                done = true;
                initMyBookmarklet();
            }
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    } else {
        initMyBookmarklet();
    }
    
    function initMyBookmarklet() {
        (window.myBookmarklet = function() {
        // JavaScript code goes here!
           
            var j = '<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/public/bookmarklet/bookmarklet.js"></script>'; 
     
            var k = '<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/public/bookmarklet/startpool.js"></script>'
     
            var y = '<a class="poolbtn" href="#poolmenu">X</a>      <nav id="poolmenu">             <ul>                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>               <li><a href="#about">About us</a>                   <ul>                        <li><a href="#about/history">History</a></li>                       <li><a href="#about/team">The team</a>                          <ul>                                <li><a href="#about/team/management">Management</a></li>                                <li><a href="#about/team/sales">Sales</a></li>                              <li><a href="#about/team/development">Development</a></li>                          </ul>                       </li>                       <li><a href="#about/address">Our address</a></li>                   </ul>               </li>               <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>             </ul>       </nav>';
     
            var b = document.createElement("div");
            b.innerHTML = j + k + y;
            document.body.appendChild(b);
            
            // STOP JAVASCRIPT BEFORE HERER
        })();
    }
})();
```

Startpool.js trigger

```
$(function() {
    $('nav#poolmenu').mmenu();
});
```

Could not fit the jQuery for the menu since it was to long but you can find it here. It has not been changed. http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/download.html

Comment: Sorry, but it looks like you are appending everything.
Maybe i'm not so javascript expert, but when you do

    InitMyBookmarklet();

you create the object

    window.myBookmarklet

that is a function itself.

But when are you executing it Or the starpool.js trigger itself?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. The top link can be used on any webpage. When you click it, it runs file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/public/bookmarklet/poolapp.js which loads all the scripts and markup for the navigation menu. However even though all these scripts are loaded, they dont add the expected classes to the nav, ul, li tags that create the menu and the menu does not open.

Comment: I'm not sure that using InnerHTML to put some <script></script> tags in the page will make them work. I think you should append them to the body as you did with the first script.